# Derivative not ignoring fields for comparison

Tags: rust, derivative

I have the following data structure. When I do a binary search on it, and pass in a `&limit_price`, it only matches if the values in `size` and `orders` matches as well. Because I am ignoring `PartialEq` I would assume it should only match on the `price` field.

Am I missing something?

```
#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Hash, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Debug)]
struct LimitPrice {
    price: OrderedFloat<f32>,

    #[derivative(Hash="ignore", PartialEq = "ignore", PartialOrd = "ignore")]
    size: OrderedFloat<f32>,
    #[derivative(Hash="ignore", PartialEq = "ignore", PartialOrd = "ignore")]
    orders: Vec<Order>,
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the `Derivative` crate, but I notice you derive `Ord` for the struct, but do not set `Ord="ignore"` for the fields you want to ignore. So `PartialOrd` may be ignoring those fields, but `Ord` does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [reproducible example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b952b69af314ab225683732ee3655cd) shows that only `Ord` is incorrect.

Any time you implement `Ord` and `PartialOrd`, you need to ensure that the implementations agree. With `#[derive]` this is automatic, but because `derivative` allows you to skip fields it also makes it possible to get `Ord` and `PartialOrd` that don't agree with each other. In this code, it would make sense for them to both have the same `"ignore"` annotation.

```
#[derivative(Hash="ignore", PartialEq = "ignore", PartialOrd = "ignore", Ord = "ignore")]
                                                                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=003c5d225ced586a707b1c5da17967b1)

`Ord` and `PartialOrd` have a different relationship than `Eq` and `PartialEq`. `Eq` is a marker trait – it has no behavior of its own, only a contract about the behavior of `PartialEq`. `Ord`, on the other hand, carries *both* a promise about the behavior of `PartialOrd` (that `partial_cmp` always returns `Some`) *and* its own behavior (a function that returns an `Ordering` directly). This is why you don't need an `"ignore"` annotation for `Eq` but you do need one for `Ord`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the great explanation. I noticed that `Eq = "ignore"` doesn't compile, so I assumed `Ord = "ignore"` also wouldn't. Adding the `Ord = "ignore"` fixes the issue.